# Adding an internal library to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jar

I'm trying to add some JARs to an Eclipse project. It used to be working, but now it's not. Previously I'd just put the JARs in /war/WEB-INF/lib (it's a Google App Engine project), then refresh the Package Explorer in Eclipse and they would show up. Then I could just right-click and choose "Add to build path" and it would add. Now, for some reason, when I refresh Package Explorer some of the JARs in the folder aren't showing up.

Is there a maximum amount of JARs that Eclipse will allow me to add? (I'm at 18 currently).

Otherwise, is there some other way that I can add these?

This is with Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a maximum amount of JARs that Eclipse will allow me to add?

No. You're probably copying the JARs to a different folder than you expect.

To check, right click the `lib` folder -> properties -> select the value for "Location" (it looks like a label but you can click into it and select the text with the mouse or right mouse button -> "Select All" or click into it and <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>)

Now try the path in a shell or explorer to see whether it contains what you think.

If the path is correct, try to restart Eclipse.

You might also want to activate the "refresh" preferences (first few items in "Workspace") so you don't have to refresh for folder manually all the time.

Comment: I was putting them in the right folder, and restarting Eclipse didn't help. However, enabling all the refresh options for Workspace made them show up.

I'm not sure why that would have worked when refreshing by right-clicking and choosing Refresh didn't, but thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, Eclipse "forgets" that F5 should refresh after you use the debugger. Not sure why. Using the menu shortcut did always work, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you can add jars to your build path.

- Right click your project and select **Properties**
- In the Properties dialog, go to **Java Build Path**
- In the **Libraries** tab you can use **Add JARs** or **Add External JARs** to add a jar to the build path

Comment: That doesn't work. Add JARs only gives you the option to add files in the Package Explorer, so if they're not showing up in Package Explorer it's not going to help.

Add External JARs will work, but it uses absolute paths in the .classpath file so if anyone else checks out my repository it won't work for them.

Comment: You can create a variable with the path and use "Add Variable" to add something relative to the variable.